# Cloudera Hadoop superuser group

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to create a group on one of my datanodes that will have superuser privileges for hdfs and associated fs commands.

So far I have:

- Checked to see that dfs.permissions.superusergroup=supergroup (default)
- Created a local group on the datanode using : groupadd supergroup
- Added a local linux user to supergroup

I still receive errors that I'm not the super user when I run "hadoop dfsadmin -report" and I should be able to access anything within the hdfs regardless of permission as a super user but I can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you did this on a DataNode, but the [HDFS Permissions Guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html) says "For HDFS, the mapping of users to groups is performed on the NameNode. Thus, the host system configuration of the NameNode determines the group mappings for the users."